# Script doesn't read file

Tags: python, file, io

I have a problem with the `read()` function in Python, it just doesn't read the file:

```
with open("D:\\Joseph\\pythontest.txt", "w+") as f:
 f.write("Hello World")
 print(f.read())
```

It doesn't show anything in the output (not even an error), just finishes the program.

[screenshot of code in Sublime IDE showing nothing printed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bd2e9.jpg)

Comment: Files don't work the way you seem to think—their contents can't be randomly written and read the way you're trying to do it. See [Reading and Writing Files](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) in the documentation for more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are writing to the file, but you didn't go back in the file. The "cursor" is located after what you wrote.

Try `f.seek(0)` to go at the beginning of your file after writing to it.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is trying to write it as you have ”w+” as a second param of open() call. Please use the open without the second parameter.